# why don't work my DataBase SQLite xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have one project and in it I create sqlite DB. Now I want read data from Sqlite and store in `NSMutableArray` and show in in `UITableView` this is my code but when I compile this program step by step. this compile jump from this line :

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, [sqlStatement_userInfo UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
```

to this line and don't working:

```
sqlite3_close(database1);
```

this is my complete code:

```
/*==================================================================
 METHOD FOR READING DATA FROM DATABASE
 ==================================================================*/
-(NSMutableArray *)readInformationFromDatabase
{
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database2;
    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([[self DatabaseSqlite] UTF8String], &database2) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        //SQLIte Statement
        NSString *sqlStatement =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select ID from Table1 where ParentID = 0"];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement2;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database2, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement2) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                // Init the Data Dictionary
                _OwnID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement2, 0)];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"No Data Found");
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement2);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database2);

    ThisParentID = _OwnID;
    do {
        // Setup the database object
        sqlite3 *database1;
        // Open the database from the users filessytem
        if(sqlite3_open([[self DatabaseSqlite] UTF8String], &database1) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
            //SQLIte Statement
            NSString *sqlStatement_userInfo =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from Table1 ParentID = %@",ThisParentID];
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, [sqlStatement_userInfo UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
                while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    // Init the Data Dictionary
                    NSMutableDictionary *_dataDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                    NSString *_recordName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                    NSString *_recordID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                    NSString *_recordParentID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                    _recordBrotherID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
                    NSString *_recordChildID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];
                    NSString *_recordType = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 5)];
                    NSString *_recordModified = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 6)];

                    ThisParentID = _recordID;

                    [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_recordName] forKey:@"Name"];
                    [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_recordID] forKey:@"ID"];
                    [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_recordParentID] forKey:@"ParentID"];
                    [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_recordBrotherID] forKey:@"BrotherID"];
                    [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_recordChildID] forKey:@"ChildID"];
                    [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_recordType] forKey:@"Type"];
                    [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_recordModified] forKey:@"Modified"];

                    [array addObject:_dataDictionary];
                }
            // Release the compiled statement from memory
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(database1);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"NOT Found");
        }
    } while (![_recordBrotherID isEqualToString:@"0"]);

    return array;
}
```

Comment: What is return value of sqlite3_prepare_v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend when you write many line code should to be careful. this code is right but in this code there are a little mistake and this mistake is in this line :

```
NSString *sqlStatement_userInfo =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from Table1 ParentID = %@",ThisParentID];
```

for reading data from SQlite with certain column you should to use of this code :

"Select * From TableName **WHERE** Column = SomeValue"

so you should change your code and write this :

```
NSString *sqlStatement_userInfo =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from Table1 Where ParentID = %@",ThisParentID];
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

You may have more chance using SQLite wrappers like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) or, even better, [iActiveRecord](https://github.com/AlexDenisov/iActiveRecord) (model based wrapper).